# Set style element for Cell Height % from remote XML

Tags: javascript, xml, styles

I'm trying to use the same JS routine I've made, which reads a remote xml and also use this to change an html style element.  I've got 80% there, but now locked.

I have a table where I'm currently using JS to locate a remote XML then get tag elements and add to the various cell contents.   This works very well.

http://jfi.net/mix

But I also want to direct the cell height %s from the same `<data-percent>` tag.

I'd added an id to the td, to allow a get operation, but I simply can't fill in the elements style in the html using the captured data-percent, even thought it's working well for the text.

I keep hitting a wall, and surely am missing something simple.

```
<tr class="tablerow text-center">
<td id="height05" style="height:6%;width:100%;border:1px solid #000;background-color:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:12px;color:#fff">

<script>
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
xmlhttp.open("GET","recipe-01.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;  
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paint05"); 
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("color-name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write(" ");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("data-percent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("%");
} 
</script>   
</td>
</tr>
```

In this case, I'm trying to use the 'data-percent' value, to either add or replace the style="height:6%"

```
<td id="height05" style="(NEED DATA PERCENT HERE);width:100%;border:1px solid #000;background-color:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:12px;color:#fff">
```

The XML file will always assure that all color element's % adds up to 100 for the table.  The table is in INCHES. (very important for printing) but the cell heights are in %s.

Answer (score 0):

Hello u can use the function setAttribute in your js :

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("color-name")[0].setAttribute('style','height:100%'));
```

Or

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("color-name")[0].style.height = '100%';
```

Comment: Thank you!   But the style.height needs to =  the <data-percent>> value.  I can't have a fixed value in the js.